# How to make div position fixed without floating

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to fix the left div using `position:fixed`. So that when I scroll the page only right div should move, I tried using `position:fixed` to left div but it was floating over right div content. How to make left div fix to the page without floating over right div ?

CSS :

```
#main{width:100%;display:table;table-layout:fixed;border:1px solid red;position:relative; }
ul{list-style:none;padding:0;margin:0;overflow-y:scroll;height:100%;}
#left {               
    display: table-cell;
    width:250px; 
    // min-width:100px;
    vertical-align:middle; 
    text-align:left;
    background:red;
    }

#right {               
    display: table-cell;
    width:100%; 
    vertical-align:middle; 
    text-align:left;
    background-color:#ccc;
}
```

Fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/0k698ga2/1/

Right div must have width:100% becasue, some pages left div was hidden, to cover the page right div must have 100%.

Comment: wen you have fixed, its relative to the window and so takes nothing into consideration of the other divs.. you will need to adjust the width of the other right div, or you could play with `z-index`

Comment: You can use CSS calc() : `#right {width: calc(100% - 250px}`.

Comment: @Pogrindis right div must have width 100% because in some pages left div is hidden, so right div should cover the entire page

Comment: fair enough, also note `calc` then is probably a far better option and quite compatible : http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/0k698ga2/2/

I used this piece of CSS. Hope it helps.

```
#main{
    width:100%;
    display:table;
    //table-layout:fixed;
    border:1px solid red;
    position:relative; 
}
ul{
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;margin:0;
//    overflow-y:scroll;
    height:100%;
}
#left {               
    display: table-cell;
    width:250px; 
    position:fixed;
    // min-width:100px;
    vertical-align:middle; 
    text-align:left;
    background:red;
}

.leftContainer {
    position:relative;
    width:250px;
}

#right {               
    display: table-cell;
    width:100%; 
    vertical-align:middle; 
    text-align:left;
    background-color:#ccc;
}
```

Comment: if i remove the left div, then it giving left side margin.. In some pages left div is hidden, so at that time right div should cover 100%

Comment: Yes in that case also it will work, all you need to do is hide the "leftContainer" div instead of left div
Also you can interchange the ids and css like http://jsfiddle.net/0k698ga2/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the following, simply add the class full-width to the body tag in order to hide the left panel and make the right full width.

```
.full-width #left {
    display: none;
}

.full-width #right {
    width: 100%;
}

#left {
    width: 25%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: red;
}

#right {
    width: 75%;
    position: relative;
    left: 25%;
}
```

Comment: right div must have width 100% because in some pages left div is hidden, so right div should cover the entire page .

Comment: Edited my answer to suit your use case. You will have to use some javascript in order to apply a CSS class to make the page full width thou.

Comment: can u provide the jsfiddle link. It shows white empty left margin.  If i remove left div..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0k698ga2/3/. Remove full-width class if you want the left hand panel to appear from the div with id main.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you set `position:fixed` with a fixed width (i.e. here `width:250px;`) on the left div and add the width as a margin to the right div, i.e. `margin-left:250px;`.
See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0qdfyjom/) or directly the css code:

```
#main{width:100%;display:table;border:1px solid red;position:relative; }
ul{list-style:none;padding:0;margin:0;overflow-y:scroll;height:100%;}
#left {               
    width:250px; 
    // min-width:100px;
    vertical-align:middle; 
    text-align:left;
    background:red;
    position:fixed;
}

#right {               
    vertical-align:middle; 
    text-align:left;
    background-color:#ccc;
    margin-left:250px;
}
```

Comment: I cant pass margin-left because some pages doesn't have left div, so if i keep margin-left to right div then it gives empty space on left side.

Comment: You could add a css class `one-column-page` to your main div if the page doesn't have the column on the left and then add a css rule `.one-column-page #right { margin-left:0px; }`.

Answer (score 0):

In your Javascript, check if the `#left` div is visible or not.

```
var leftDiv = document.querySelector("#left"),
    rightDiv = document.querySelector("#right");
if(leftDiv.getBoundingClientRect().width === 0 && leftDiv.getBoundingClientRect().height === 0) {
     rightDiv.classList.add("fullWidth");
} else {
     rightDiv.classList.remove("fullWidth");
}
```

Now by default in your CSS:

```
#right {
   width: calc(100% - 250px);
}
```

For fullWidth:

```
#right.fullWidth {
   width: 100%;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedrias/8d15tL1b/)**

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to `#left` for hidden status.

```
/* Left panel visible */
#right {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 250px;
}

/* Left panel hidden */
#left.hidden {
    display: none;
}
#left.hidden + #right {
    padding-left: 0;
}
```